# shinyApp - How to copy a value from selectInput and paste to a reactive table

Tags: r, shiny, copy, paste

I want to copy values from a selectInput and paste it to a reactive table. Below is an example.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

df<-data.frame("Name" = c("apple","cherry"),
               "Value" = c(5,6))

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("fruit"),
 fluidRow(DT::DTOutput("table1")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  df1 <- reactiveValues(data = {df})
  
  output$table1 = DT::renderDT({
    DT::datatable(df1$data, editable = T)
  })
  
  output$fruit <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "fruit_name",
      label = "Name",
      multiple = TRUE,
      choices = c("apple","cherry","pear", "peach","banana"),
      selected = "apple"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

I hope to be able to choose a fruit name from selectInput, copy it, and paste it to the table under column "Name". It seems shinyApp doesn't support regular copy and paste. Anyway to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to select the text inside an item. With the code below, you can select an item and use **Ctrl-C** and **Ctrl-V** to copy and paste it.

```r
js <- '
document.addEventListener("copy", (event) => {
  const anchorNode = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
  if (anchorNode instanceof HTMLElement &&
    anchorNode.classList.contains("selectize-input")) {
    const items = Array.from(anchorNode.getElementsByClassName("item active"));
    const string = items.map(i => i.innerText).join(", ");
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", string);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  uiOutput("fruit"),
  fluidRow(DTOutput("table1"))
)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! I guess there is no other way to do it.